# Django: what kind of exceptions does create_user throw?

Tags: django, exception

I want to catch them and return helpful messages to the user. The documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/ says ValueError is raised when given an invalid username. There's also IntegrityError, when the username already exists. Are these all?

Is this the usual way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not using Django Auth Forms then you have to do the validation manually. The simple way is when user submit the custom form you should check:

- if username is valid, match with the regex e.g. \w+
- check if username is already taken or not e.g. `User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()`
- check if email is already used for an account e.g. `User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()`
- then create the user

FYI: there are some already Django Auth packages e.g. [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth), [django-userena](http://www.django-userena.org/) and many more which handles all the stuff pretty well, instead of reinventing the wheel by your self.

Answer (score 0):

You can always take a look at source code easily since their moved to [Github](https://github.com/django/django) or find it in Python `site-packages` directory on your machine.

Just go to `django/contrib/auth/` and analyze some code.